# Jenkins API created Jobs don't have Build Now button

Tags: jenkins

I am using the Jenkins remote access API for copying a job from an existing job. However, this job isn't buildable unless I go to the UI and press configure, and then click Save (even without making any changes). Why are my API created jobs not buildable via the API?

Comment: I read another response the copy jobs are created disabled, see [JENKINS-25595](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-25595). Otherwise, you'd have 2 identical jobs that might fire together; rarely sesirable. You could make a call to enable. `curl -X POST JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/enable`

Answer (score 0):

So after fiddling a bit, disabling the build by calling /disable and then calling /enable works. For me, only calling /enable didn't work, I had to call /disable first.